# loki added to grafana as data source, unable to see all namespaces and pods

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-alerts

i have installed grafana and loki in my  kubernetes cluster, in grafana dashboard i am unable to see all the namespaces and pods. can any one guide me to reslove this issue , added loki as data source in grafana. Thank you.

showing only few namespaces and pods

i want to see all my pods and namespaces in grafana dashboard

Comment: Can loki itself see your targets?